# How to create .pri file with Qt creator

Tags: ide, qt-creator

I'm trying to learn qmake, but can't find a native way to create .pri file with qt creator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new **.pri** file with Qt Creator as follows:

1. Select **File** in the menu bar.
2. Select **New File or Project...**.
3. Choose **General** under **Files and Classes** on the **New** dialog.
4. Give the name of your file with extension, for example: **test.pri**.

(I'm using Qt Creator 2.4.1.)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of actions on Qt Creator 4.12.0 on MacOS

[image: New File or Project]
[image: Select empty file]
[image: Write file name and path]